# Video in jumbotron

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to get a video into a Bootstrap 4 jumbotron but I am running into a weird issue: my content is covering up the video. Obviously I don't want that. The gap on mobile between the jumbotron and the content also gets huge on mobile. I've been trying to fix that as well but with no luck. I've also tried other answers to this question on here and they didn't work either.
Here is my code so far:

```css
/* JUMBOTRON 
------------------------------------------------- */
.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
  height: 62.5vh;
  padding: 0px !important;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.video-background {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
}





/* USP CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */


.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;

}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: .75rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
}


/* FEATURES AND QUOTES
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 5rem 0; 
  width: 15%;
 
  height: 4px;
  border-top: 2px solid #FFD963;
}


.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -.05rem;
}


/* RESPONSIVE STUFF
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .featurette-heading {
    margin-top: 7rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main role="main">

      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <video class="video-background" preload muted autoplay loop>
          <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        </video>
        
      </div>


      <!-- -->

      <div class="container marketing mt-0">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h2>This is the first</h2>
            <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
            
          </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
            
          </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
            
          </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->


        <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

        <hr class="featurette-divider yellowline">

        

        <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->

      </div><!-- /.container -->


      <!-- FOOTER -->
      <footer class="container">
        <p class="float-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
        <p>&copy; 2022 &middot; </p>
        <p>
          <a href="#">link 1</a>          
          <a href="#">link 2</a>        
          <a href="#">link 3</a>      
        </p>
      </footer>
    </main>
```

Link to [Codepen](https://codepen.io/amyscotteng/pen/xxXyOJe)

Thank you for any help you can provide! I know I should upgrade to Bootstrap 5 but I haven't had time to learn it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest your `background-video` into a section and declare the section to be `height: 100vh;` this will automatically push your other content down below. To demonstrate, I called the section `section#video`. I also moved your `main` to start below that section. See the changes I made in CSS and HTML.

```css
/* JUMBOTRON 
------------------------------------------------- */

.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
  
  padding: 0px !important;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.video-background {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
}

section#video {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: fit-content;
}

section#main-sec {
  height: 100%;
}


/* USP CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: .75rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
}


/* FEATURES AND QUOTES
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 5rem 0;
  width: 15%;
  height: 4px;
  border-top: 2px solid #FFD963;
}

.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -.05rem;
}


/* RESPONSIVE STUFF
-------------------------------------------------- */
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<section id="video">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <video class="video-background" preload muted autoplay loop>
          <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        </video>

  </div>
</section>


<section id="main-sec">
<!-- -->
<main role="main">
  <div class="container marketing">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
        <h2>This is the first</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>

      </div>
      <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>

      </div>
      <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>

      </div>
      <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->


    <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

    <hr class="featurette-divider yellowline">



    <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->

  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->


  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer class="container">
    <p class="float-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
    <p>&copy; 2022 &middot; </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">link 1</a>
      <a href="#">link 2</a>
      <a href="#">link 3</a>
    </p>
  </footer>
</main>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! Do you have any idea how to get rid of that huge gap that shows up when you shrink the page? I've looked at the classes specified and there's nothing that is adding extra padding.

Comment: @metalcoder see the adjusted.

Comment: THANK YOU! It works perfectly now!